# Best way to recover from HSQLDB LOBS file growth

Tags: hsqldb

I have a HSQLDB database with lots of LOBs. The LOB file has grown to a point where it is causing the machine to crash.

I have some data in the LOBs file which can be deleted.

What is the best way to deal with this situation? Will performing a backup only export the actual LOBs or will the file be exported with the internal space? (i.e the whole sparse LOBs file)

I have tried CHECKPOINT DEFRAG but this doesn't seem to work in 2.3.2, the LOBs file continues to grow after deleting the unused LOBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 2.3.4 a CHECKPOINT results in the truncation of the `.lobs` file to the last LOB that is referenced in database tables. Any empty spaces within the file will then be reused for future lobs.

If there are relatively few live lobs in the database, you can convert the type of columns with LOBs to VARCHAR or VARBINARY, perform a CHECKPOINT, then SHUTDOWN, and then delete the .lobs file. You can then reopen and convert the column types back to CLOB and BLOB.